# How to append several lines of text in a file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I want to write several lines (5 or more) to a file I'm going to create in script. I can do this by `echo >> filename`. But I would like to know what the best way to do this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use a here document:

```
cat <<EOF >> outputfile
some lines
of text
EOF
```

Comment: +1: But works only with fixed text, not generated in script. No vars substitution etc. right?

Comment: @Valentin: It will do variable, arithmetic and command substitution unless you suppress it by quoting the opening delimiter like this, for example: `'EOF'`.

Comment: Ive been unable to get the `-` modifier to work.  AS n `cat <<-EOF >> out` which should strip whitespace

Answer (score 5):

I usually use the so-called "here-document" Dennis suggested. An alternative is:

```
(echo first line; echo second line) >> outputfile
```

This should have comparable performance in bash, as (....) starts a subshell, but echo is 'inlined' - bash does not run /bin/echo, but does the echo by itself.

It might even be faster because it involves no exec().

This style is even more useful if you want to use output from another command somewhere in the text.

Comment: to avoid creating a subshell, you can use braces for grouping.  Just remember to end the command list with a semicolon and separate the braces with spaces -- `{ echo first; echo second; } >> outputfile`